# Automatically import data to hidden excel worksheet

Tags: excel, automation

Small preamble:
I started working with a new company. The guy before me made this excel file but made it impossible to modify, and now that we're changing the protocol, the company is a bit in a  pinch.

What the original file does:
When opening the file, a data import wizard pops up immediately, asking for a source. Once the source is selected, it uploads the data in a hidden worksheet, and the main worksheet makes its calculation. The User experience is: one opens the file, selects the correct .csv, and he's done.

I managed to redo almost everything; I reproduced the calculations, made an hidden sheet, and formatted the wizard so that the data imported are correct, but no matter how hard I tried or look on the internet, I could not make the wizard window pop up when opening the file.
Does anybody know how to make the data import window pop-ups immediately when opening the excel file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "wizard window" ? Is it a UserForm ? Are you using `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` ?

Comment: You might need to use some VBA Macros, that run on [Workbook_Open event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.Open) (i.e. run when the workbook is opened).

Comment: Judging from visual basic, in the original file, I cannot see any code line.
For wizard window, I mean the window that opens if you click on import from CSV in the data ribbon

Comment: What is the file extension of the original Excel file ?

Comment: the origina l file is an .xlsx

Comment: Maybe Power Query then ? Check  `Data tab > Get Data > Launch Power Query Editor` or Check  `Data tab > Existing Connections`

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:

I ended up recording a macro and then modify the close using:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
so that it would run on the start up